# Creating a grid of images

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, grid

My users are currently able to select a number of items from a list using select boxes. I have a piece of code which checks the database for each item and outputs their details.

Each item has an image. The images are visual ID tags which are generated on-the-fly and are not actually stored anywhere. I am currently using the WideImage PHP library to generate these images. I need to be able to generate the images for the items that the user selects and then combine them into either one image or in a grid that can fit on an A4 sized page (for printing purposes). A total of 8 of these images can fit on an A4 page (2 columns, 4 rows).

My code currently looks like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['print']);$i++){
    $ids = $checkbox[$i];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = '".$ids."'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){           
        $item_name = $row['name']; // used when generating image
    }

    // WideImage PHP code (to generate image)
    $image1 = WideImage::load('photos/image1.png')->resize(325, 225); // base image
    $image2 = WideImage::load('photos/image2.png');
    $image3 = WideImage::load($item_name);
    $smaller = $image2->resize('124', '158', 'fill');
    $result = $image1->merge($smaller, "196", "5", 100);
    $finalimage = $result->merge($image3, "12", "1", 100);        
}
```

I am stuck up until this point. I do not know how to 'combine' these images into one big image or place them individually into a grid. Would it be easier to pre-generate the images and store a path to the image in the database?

Even if I did have all of the images already generated, how would I combine them into one big image or into a grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the resized images to a cache folder, then output them like you would a normal image using the `<img />` tag. This way, you can even skip the images that are already in the cache folder (assuming you name them according to the height and width, `e.g. image1-325x225.png`)

Check out how to write an image to file: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/documentation/saving-images/

After you have output them in html, you can use CSS to style them. Or output them as a table. That's up to you.

Comment: Thanks Lian. I ended up writing all of the images to a temporary folder, formatting them for output using CSS and then emptying the directory.

Comment: Ok, that was what I meant. Although, if you didn't empty the directory, you could reuse the images (if they have unique filenames). Up to you.